# What to do when Laravel 10 middleware Request $request has null value?

Tags: php, laravel

I am experiencing a problem in my  laravel 10 custom middleware, when i try to access the page that is  protected with my custom middleware, with a code that is in the database to use as an access, the !temporary condition always activate, and when i try to check it with the use of " dd(); " on  why it is happening i found out that the request is empty. and i still don't know why the request is null? Any suggestion?

```
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
         dd($request->all()); // has a null value

        $code = $request->input('srvy_keycode');

        // Check if a code exists in the database
        $temporaryCode = ClientCode::where('code', $code)->first();

        if (!$temporaryCode) {
            // Code is invalid; you can return a response, redirect, or abort here
            return redirect()->route('clientSecurity')->with('message', 'Invalid code');
        }

        // Code is valid, proceed to the next middleware or route
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

i try to register it in the app/http/kernel.php

```
protected $middlewareAliases = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'checkcode' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckSurveyCode::class, //my cusstom middleware
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'auth.session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'precognitive' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\HandlePrecognitiveRequests::class,
        'signed' => \App\Http\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];
```

the Route i'm using with my custom middleware and the routes that were user should go if it hasn't give the  correct code.

```
 Route::get('/home/clientSurvey', 'showClientSurvey')->name('ClientSurvey')->middleware('checkcode');

 Route::get('/home/clientSecurity', 'surveySecurity')->name('clientSecurity');
    Route::post('/home/clientSecurity', 'checkSecurity');
});
```

the process it should go if its correct

```
 public function checkSecurity(Request $request)
    {
        
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'srvy_keycode' => 'required'
        ]);

        // Access the validated data
        $code = $validatedData['srvy_keycode'];

        // Check if the code exists in the database
        $temporaryCode = ClientCode::where('code', $code)->first();

        // Additional checks, if needed
        if ($temporaryCode) {
            return redirect()->route('ClientSurvey');
        }

        return back()->with('message', 'Error');
    }
```

Comment: you have to register your middleware in the ``protected $routeMiddleware = [
   // other middlewares
    // your middleware
];``

Comment: also, you have set the middleware to only ``/home/clientSurvey`` route !

Comment: it still doesn't work

Comment: Make sure you always clear laravels caches, use `artisan route:clear` or `artisan optmize:clear` or even better, disable caches entirely for local development, set the cache driver to `CACHE_DRIVER=array` and run `artisan optimize:clear` and don't run any of the cache commands. You might be running in circles while laravel hits a cache and doesn't actually run any of your changed route lines.

Comment: Are you hinting the correct type for `Request`? What `use` statement do you have at the top of the file? the service container could be finding the wrong item.